# How to make a service working when the screen is locked?

Tags: android, service, notifications

I have an app, has a service.. its working normally when screen is on....
but service not working when the screen is locked....
notification not working when screen is locked...

```
private void _startService() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Mulai service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() { checkAlarm(); }
        },0, 60000);
}
```

Comment: Check this post regarding PARTIAL_WAKELOCK: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360234/partial-wake-lock-and-thread-running-in-a-service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7360234/partial-wake-lock-and-thread-running-in-a-service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the WakeLock. See this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

[Android application working with locked screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836950/android-application-working-with-locked-screen)